# What is the difference between RAM and TM?

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models

In algorithm analysis, we assume a generic one processor Random Access Machine (RAM). As far as I know, the RAM machine is no more efficient than the Turing machine. All algorithms can be implemented in the Turing machine. So my questions are:

- If the Turing machine is as efficient as the RAM machine, then why are we not assuming Turing machine for algorithm analysis?
- What is the difference between RAM and TM?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turing machines are not as efficient as RAM machines. A RAM machine can access an arbitrary tape location in $O(1)$. A Turing machine can't. A RAM machine can do arithmetic in $O(1)$ (under certain restrictions). A Turing machine can't.

Turing machines polynomially simulate RAM machines, that is, for some constant $c$, any RAM machine running in time $O(n^k)$ can be simulated by a Turing machine running in time $O(n^{ck})$. (The constant is pretty reasonable, about $2$, depending on the Turing machine model.)

Comment: Thanks Yuval.Now I understand that RAM is faster than Turing machine.but why 2?

Comment: I get $2$ since that's (roughly) the time it naively takes to simulate random access. I could be wrong here.

Comment: You should have a look at [Cook's *Time Bounded Random Access Machines*](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~sacook/homepage/rams.pdf), where the overhead in simulating one model with another is precisely proved.

Comment: Just a quick question: If a problem $\Pi$ has a polynomial-time algorithm on the RAM model, can I say that $\Pi$ has a polynomial-time algorithm on the TM model? Or alternatively, If a problem $\Pi$ has a polynomial-time algorithm on the RAM model, can I say that $\Pi$ is in P?

Comment: @Azzo You are correct, a problem is in P iff it has a polynomial time algorithm in the RAM model iff it has a polynomial time algorithm in the Turing machine model.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you. My question comes from **the sums of square roots problem:** Given two sequences $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ and $b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n$ of positive integers, is $A := \sum_i \sqrt{a_i}$ less than, equal to, or greater than $B := \sum_i \sqrt{b_i}$?

I read that this problem has a trivial $O(n)$-time algorithm on the real RAM (compute the sums and compare them) but this does not imply membership in P. Why it does not imply membership in P?

Comment: @Azzo This is the real RAM model, where you can do real arithmetic for free, rather than the RAM model, where you can do small integer arithmetic for free. (Here *free* means constant time.)

Comment: Ah ok, I did not know about the real RAM. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus when you say a problem is in P iff it has a polynomial time algorithm in the RAM model iff it has a polynomial time algorithm in the Turing machine model, are you referring to a RAM with constant-time multiplication?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia The RAM model has constant-time operations on words of length $O(\log n)$.

Comment: What is $n$ here, the initial length of the word?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia Here $n$ is the length of the input, in bits.

Comment: So you're saying the set of allowed algorithms is restricted to have only those such that words grow in length only logarithmically in the size of the input, right? Wouldn't this restriction prohibit something like squaring, as the length doubles and hence is linear in the length of the input?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia A single variable can span multiple words, just as in real life. See for example the GMP library.

Comment: This is a different definition of a RAM than Cook's [as seen here](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~sacook/homepage/rams.pdf), right? Do you have a reference on the one you're talking about - word length restrictions, constant-time multiplication? The literature on RAMs consists of a zoo of different restrictions either on the amount or cost of operations or of word lengths, and sometimes complexity classes don't hold up between RAMs.

Comment: Yes, the models seem different. My model is the "RAM with words of logarithmic width". This might be the same model as the [transdichotomous model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transdichotomous_model) which is apparently popular in computational geometry.